# Pyspark Dataframe returning data as the column Names

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

Im trying to query data of a table from one dev-01 workspace to dev-02 workspace by using an JDBC URL connection. But while doing that the values in the dataframe are coming as the header names.

[image: Data Output]

The code which im using is below

```
test_query = f"""SELECT
 customer_short_code,
channel_name
FROM (
SELECT
customer_short_code,
channel_name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cast(customer_short_code as string) ORDER BY 
cast(channel_name as string) ) AS row_num
FROM
table_name where sales_subregion_name NOT LIKE 'Cerv. %' -- Replace with the actual 
table name
) AS RankedChannels
WHERE row_num = 1
"""
df_poc_sales = read_from_sandbox(jdbcUrl=dev_jdbc_url,query=test_query)
display(df_poc_sales)
```

The read from sandbox function is as below

```
def read_from_sandbox(jdbcUrl: str, query: str):
"""
Method is used to read data from sandbox instance

Args :
  jdbcUrl : jdbcurl of sandbox instance
  query : query is used to read dat
Return:
   spark dataframe
"""

df = (
    spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", jdbcUrl)
    .option("query", query)
    .option("driver", "com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver")
    .load()
)
return df
```

Upon analysis found that the issue is due to the row number or any window function. When i comment the code of the window function the code runs perfectly fine.

Has anyone faced any issue similar to this .

Thanks

Comment: i feel like the `test_query` string may be interpreted as having single quotes:  `SELECT 'customer_short_code', 'channel_name' FROM ...` which will lead to the behavior you're seeing. does explicitly using double quotes for the columns like `SELECT "customer_short_code", "channel_name" FROM ...` make a difference?

Comment: @DerekO Thanks for the reply, i guess the string interpretation that's not the issue, because when i comment the row_number function the data is coming properly

Comment: When using a window function, you have to first partition by a specific column and then order the data within each partition.
If you do not specify a partition, Spark will treat the entire dataset as a single partition and sort all the data together.

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Hey thanks for replying, and yes i did give  an partition column

Comment: def read_from_sandbox(jdbc_url: str, query: str):    
    df = (
        spark.read.format("jdbc")
        .option("url", jdbc_url)
        .option("query", query)
        .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
        .option("user", user)
        .option("password", password)
        .load()
    )    
    return df

Comment: test_query = f"""SELECT customer_short_code, channel_name
FROM (
  SELECT customer_short_code, channel_name, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cast(customer_short_code as nvarchar) ORDER BY cast(channel_name as nvarchar) ) AS row_num
  FROM (
    SELECT customer_short_code, channel_name
    FROM table02 
    WHERE sales_subregion_name NOT LIKE 'Cerv. %'
  ) AS subquery
) AS RankedChannels
WHERE row_num = 1
"""
result_df = read_from_sandbox(jdbc_url, test_query)
result_df.show()

Comment: The above worked for me can you try and let me know if it helped

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Thanks for the help, the driver you provided was for SQLServerDriver, and when applied its throwing an error saying the JDBC connection wasnt able to open as the location "The driver could not open a JDBC connection" as  i was trying to connect is an Databricks delta table. So i tried an different approach the query which i provided was a small part of larger query, so i converted my entire SQL code to Pyspark and Viola it worked. After this exercise i realized that the JDBC driver has some limitations and wasn't able to convert my SQL Code properly

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Query SQL Server with Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/connect/external-systems/sql-server) the driver to connect to Azure sql table is

```
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```

I have tried in the pyspark:
In the below code I have defined the window specification.
Applying the transformations in PySpark.

```
window_spec = Window().partitionBy("customer_short_code").orderBy("channel_name")
def read_from_sandbox(jdbc_url: str, query: str):
    df = (
        spark.read.format("jdbc")
        .option("url", jdbc_url)
        .option("query", query)
        .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
        .option("user", user)
        .option("password", password)
        .load()
    )
    return df
table02 = read_from_sandbox(jdbc_url, "SELECT * FROM table02 WHERE sales_subregion_name NOT LIKE 'Cerv. %'")
result_df = (
    table02
    .withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(window_spec))
    .filter(F.col("row_num") == 1)
    .select("customer_short_code", "channel_name")
)
result_df.show()
```

**Results :**

```
+-------------------+------------+
|customer_short_code|channel_name|
+-------------------+------------+
|          customer1|    channelA|
|          customer2|    channelC|
+-------------------+------------+
```